# Sharing a large node modules directory between React Native projects

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, node-modules

Ok, 
Starting on reactNative I've noticed that the node_modules folder is huge. 210Mb to be exact. How can I share it between projects with a directory structure along these lines:

- ReactNative

  - node_modules
  - awesomeProject1
  - awesomeProject2

In bower I know there is a bower.rc file in which one can configure the bower_components path. Is there an equivalent in the package.json and is it a good practice in general for ReactNative project?

P.S
I know Hard drives are exceptionally large nowadays but somehow I managed to stuff my Mac's SSD almost to its full capacity.

Comment: Generally with node you'd use `npm link` but symlinks are unfortunately not supported by React Native Packager.

Comment: Some one found solution for this ?

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: @diego I am now developing RN on Chrome with React-web. It allows me to share node_modules between projects.

Comment: @Guy, What it's the share process for node_modules ? and the one for the  compenants of react native of other projet ? Thank

Comment: The configuration is a webpack config that runs react-web. React-web allows you to run on Chrome and thus you can use yarn link and yarn unlink for your libraries and symlinks for 3rd parties node_modules @diego